# what does 24bit mean exactly when referring to .PNG image file

Tags: png

What does it mean exactly if someones asks me for a .PNG file which is 24bit?

Comment: Welcome on GD.SO, Andrew. A simply answer to this question could find with a simple search, for example see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth). If your question requires more detail, please write some more.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini **GD.SE** - We are not [so] ;)

Comment: Stack Overflow is technically still part of the Stack Exchange network, so that would be **SO.SE**

Comment: @CAI a typo... :-P (but I'm still very fond on SO, perhaps unconsciously I'd like a fusion of GD and SO!).

Comment: I agree with Pablo. Actually this question is still more generic. If a person asks for a 24 bit png, that person needs a 24 bit png.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually quite simple. You have few types of PNG files.

**1) PNG-8,** which stands for 8 bit, supports up to 256 colour indexed palette. Which works very similar to GIF files.

**2) PNG-24** works very similar to PNG-8, it however supports to over 16 million colours (2^24 = 16,777,216 to be exact).

**3) PNG-32** which is pretty much PNG-24 + Full alpha transparency

Comment: In particular, PNG-24 refers to the 24-bit pixel size, 8 bits per color (the PNG spec calls this a color-type 2, bit-depth 8 image).

Comment: Photoshop doesn't support it but you can also make a PNG-8 with a full 8-bit transparency. I like to call in a PNG-16 :)